# Omit array from multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following arrays

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'measurements',
    'title' => 'Measurements',
    'fields' => array(  
        array(
            'name' => 'Select Units of Measurement',
            'id' => 'units',
            'type' => 'radio',
            'options' => array(
                array('name' => 'Pounds', 'value' => 'Pounds'),
                array('name' => 'Kilos', 'value' => 'Kilos'),
                array('name' => 'Ton', 'value' => 'Ton'),
                array('name' => 'Short Ton', 'value' => 'Short Ton')
            )
        ),      
        array(
            'name' => 'Displacement',
            'id' => 'displacement',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Gross Tonnage',
            'id' => 'gross_tonnage',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => ''
        )
      )
)

//more meta_boxes[] arrays continued...
```

When using a foreach loop to get elements from arrays in the `fields` array how can I omit one array? For example omit looping through the first array in 'fields' with id = `units` ? Or any other array for that matter.

```
foreach ($meta_boxes as $metabox) {
    foreach ( $metabox['fields'] as $field ) {      
        echo $field['name']; //field name       
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the keyword `continue` together with an if condition to continue with the next entity in your loop.

To skip more than one `$field` with a specific `id` I recommend this

```
foreach ($meta_boxes as $metabox) {
    foreach ( $metabox['fields'] as $field ) {      
        if (in_array ($field['id'], array ('units', 'gross_tonnage'))
            continue;

        echo $field['name']; //field name       
    }      
}
```

If it's only one use something as this:

```
foreach ($meta_boxes as $metabox) {
    foreach ( $metabox['fields'] as $field ) {      
        if ($field['id'] == 'units')
            continue;

        echo $field['name']; //field name       
    }      
}
```

---

Documentation of the [keyword continue](http://se.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($meta_boxes as $metabox) {
    foreach ( $metabox['fields'] as $field ) {      
        if ($field['id'] == 'units') continue;
        echo $field['name']; //field name       
    }      
}
```

[Continue keyword documentation](http://nz.php.net/continue)

Comment: Thank you! `continue` seems to be very efficient.